# Use dig to detect an eventual CDM use

Tags: cdn, dig

How can I check with a Digg command if a website is using CDN ? For exemple if I use this website, http://www.cdnplanet.com/tools/cdnfinder/#site:http://www.spiegel.de he tell me that the website is using Akamai . But with dig command I can not see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sajal@sajal-desktop:~$ dig cdn2.spiegel.de

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1.1 <<>> cdn2.spiegel.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40559
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cdn2.spiegel.de.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cdn2.spiegel.de.    3516    IN  CNAME   cdn.spiegel.de.edgesuite.net.
cdn.spiegel.de.edgesuite.net. 3516 IN   CNAME   a1983.g.akamai.net.
a1983.g.akamai.net. 19  IN  A   184.50.85.166
a1983.g.akamai.net. 19  IN  A   184.50.85.102

;; Query time: 113 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 06 23:23:51 ICT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 147

sajal@sajal-desktop:~$
```

edgesuite.net and akamai.net are hostnames that Amakai uses for cdn.